# GraphQL HOC messes with ref to children | React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am using React and Apollo for my project.

I got this in my component `MenuModal`:

```
onClick = () => {
    console.log(this.child)
    this.child.onSubmit(); // do stuff
};

render() {
    return (
        <Modal.Content scrolling>
            <MenuEdit
                ref={ref => (this.child = ref)} // Using ref to access it's properties
                selectedValues={selectedValues}
                match={match}
                menu={menu}
            />
```

My component `MenuEdit` has a function defined in class:

```
onSubmit = values => {
    console.log('calling inner form submit', values);
    if (this.child) {
        this.child.submitFromOutside();
    }
};
```

I should be able to call `onSubmit` from `MenuModal` right?

But I am currently getting this:
[image]

And when I console.log `this.child` in my `onClick` function I can see this:

[image]
So there's no `onSubmit` function there. When seeing `GraphQL` I wondered if it had something to do with me exporting the component with the graphQL HOC.

```
export default compose(
    graphql(UPDATE_MENU, { name: 'updateMenu' }),
    withApollo,
    withRouter
)(MenuEdit);
```

And when I changed it just to:

```
export default MenuEdit;
```

I can see my function
[image]

So I wonder how I write my export so I still can access my function in my child. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The HOC wrapps your component into another component. You can see this in the [React devtools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools). You will see that the component renders a component around your wrapped component. Something like this

```
<Apollo(ChildComponent)>
  <ChildComponent />
</Apollo>
```

Your ref then points to the `Apollo(ChildComponen)` element instance.

What you are doing here looks like an antipattern to me. In React we usually don't call functions on rendered elements (except sometimes DOM elements). The idea is rather that children call functions of their parents by receiving them as properties. The best thing in your case is to get rid of the reference and move your state and actions up the component chain. Alternatively you can use the new [render prop style](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html#basic) in `react-apollo`.

Answer (score 0):

There was a contribution to the Apollo repository to address this issue...
https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/pull/410

Wrapping your component export like this `withApollo(Component, { withRef: true })` will expose your child methods. Accessible using `ref.current.wrappedInstance`.